# Difference between `File::exist?` and `File::exists?`

Tags: ruby

On [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-exist-3F), the documentation entries for `File::exist?` and `File::exists?` are duplicated with different semantics: one entry says returns `true` if `file_name` is a directory; the other says returns `true` if `file_name` is a file.

I don't think either entry is correct. Both methods seem to be implemented in [`file.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/file.c#L5444) using `rb_file_exist_p`, which, seems to try to call `fstat()` if the value passed is an IO, or `stat()` if it's a string. Both `fstat()` and `stat()` return `0` on success and `-1` on error, and this is passed back to `rb_file_exist_p`, and turned into a boolean result. It seems to me that

1. there are two methods for making code read more easily; there are no semantic differences
2. neither really relates to a *file* existing, but to whether a *file-like* item exists, e.g. a file, a dir, a socket, a fifo etc.
3. perhaps the document could say that the methods tell the caller whether or not a thing that has file-like semantics is there, but more specific tests will tell what it actually is: e.g. directory?, file?, socket? etc.

Is my understanding of the (lack of) difference in the methods correct, and is it worth suggesting a change to the document ?

Comment: This should be asked on Ruby-talk, where it can make a difference. Or, you could check out the source code on git, make the change and make a pull request. Personally, I don't think it's a big issue since `-e` ("exists") is a flag at the OS level on *nix systems that handles both files and directories equally. That there are separate entries for files and directories was a minor point to me. In general this question isn't a good fit for SO I think, and seems to fall under the "not constructive" category.

Comment: @theTinMan: I'd have to disagree, I think that clarification of confused and broken documentation is a practical programming problem that would, at least, fall under *practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that the answer to this question depends on the Ruby version. See the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542641/479863) for newer versions of Ruby. AFAIK `exists?` was deprecated in 2.2.

---

If we look at the C source, [we see this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/file.c#L5387):

```
rb_cFile = rb_define_class("File", rb_cIO);
/* ... */
define_filetest_function("exist?", rb_file_exist_p, 1);
define_filetest_function("exists?", rb_file_exist_p, 1);
```

So `File.exist?` and `File.exists?` are exactly the same thing and the corresponding documentation is:

```
Return <code>true</code> if the named file exists.
```

The `rb_file_exist_p` C function is just a very thin wrapper around [`rb_stat`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/file.c#L810), that's a wrapper for the `STAT` macro, and [`STAT`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/file.c#L75) is just a portability wrapper for the `stat` system call. So, the documentation above is correct: `File#exist?` returns `true` if the file exists.

If we check `file.c` for the documentation snippet that talks about directories, [we find this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/file.c#L1090):

```
/*
 * Document-method: exist?
 *
 * call-seq:
 *   Dir.exist?(file_name)   ->  true or false
 *   Dir.exists?(file_name)   ->  true or false
 *
 * Returns <code>true</code> if the named file is a directory,
 * <code>false</code> otherwise.
 *
 */
```

So it looks like the documentation generator is getting confused because `Dir.exist?` and `File.exist?` are documented in `file.c` even though [`Dir` is defined in `dir.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/dir.c#L2044).

The underlying problem seems to be that the source code arrangement doesn't match what the documentation generator expects and the result is confused and incorrect documentation. I'm not sure how this should be fixed though.

Comment: OK, I hadn't considered the generators - I'll see how one goes about submitting patches to that/those - cheers

Comment: I think the obvious fix is either 1) tell the RDoc developers that they are standing on an invalid premise or 2) suggest the Ruby developers to move the `Dir.exist?` and `Dir.exists?` documentation to `dir.c`.

Comment: I think I'll try the second one - need to check the mailing list to see if its been suggested before - the doc should be in the file the functionality is defined in, but there may be a perfectly good, but not obvious, reason its not there

Comment: Great investigative dive into the code to discover the answer. Unfortunately, this answer is now out of date because these methods are not the same anymore. `File.exists?` is deprecated. See the other answers for more info.

Comment: @ClintPachl Thanks for the reminder, I've added a disclaimer.

Comment: @muistooshort Would you be able to add the version number(s) of Ruby to which your answer applies, please?

Comment: @BenSandeen AFAIK `exists?` was deprecated in 2.2 as noted by [Daniel Romero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542641/479863) below.

Answer (score 12):

Since ruby 2.2.0 `File.exists?` is deprecated use instead `File.exist?`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#exist-3F-method

Answer (score 10):

`File.exist?` and `File.exists?` are NOT exactly the same thing anymore. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/file.c#L5920

```
define_filetest_function("exist?", rb_file_exist_p, 1);
define_filetest_function("exists?", rb_file_exists_p, 1);
```

`rb_file_exists_p` contains this line:

```
rb_warning("%sexists? is a deprecated name, use %sexist? instead", s, s);
```

So you should stick with `File.exist?`.

Answer (score 2):

git pull made it go away - this was fixed [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?revision=36120&view=revision) - not sure why generated doco on ruby-doc and apidock still wrong